# List doesn't show after android native build application

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have Ext.dataview.List, I successfully can see it in my browser. But after buildind my application for android list and it's title doesn't shown. I tried almost everything but noghing helps.

Here is my code:

MenuTabPanel.js:

```
Ext.define('App.view.MenuTabPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'menutb',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.dataview.List'
],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    fullscreen : true,
    id: 'menuTabPanel',
    //layout: 'fit',

     listeners: {
            painted : function(element, eOpts) {
                        if(this.getActiveItem()) {
                            var title = this.getActiveItem().child('[xtype=list]').title;
                            var navBar = Ext.getCmp('navMenu').getNavigationBar();
                            navBar.setTitle(title);
                        }   
                    } 
     } 
},

initialize: function() {                
    var content = [];
    //var menuStore = Ext.getStore('menuItemsStore');
    var menuStore = Ext.create('App.store.MenuItemsStore'); 

    var onMenuItemClicked = function(list, index, node,record){
        var navigateTo = Ext.create('App.view.' + record.get('Id') + 'View');
        var navMenu = Ext.getCmp('navMenu');
        navMenu.push(navigateTo);
    };
    var tabPanel = this;
     var onStoreLoad = function(){
        menuStore.filter("Level",1);
        menuStore.each(function(record) {
            var tabItem = {};
            var items = {};
            tabItem['iconCls'] = record.get('Id');
            tabItem['layout'] = 'fit';

            items['id'] = record.get('Id');
            items['title'] = record.get('Title');
            items['xtype'] = 'list';
            items['height'] = '100%';
            items['width'] = '100%';
            //items['layout'] = 'vbox';
            //items['flex'] = 1;
            items['itemTpl'] = '<div class="menuitem-text"><img src="../resources/icons/{Id}.png" /> {Title}</div>';
            //items['store'] = Ext.getStore('menuItemsStore');
            var listen = {};
            listen['itemtap'] = onMenuItemClicked;
            items['listeners'] = listen;
            tabItem['items'] = [items]; 
            content.push(tabItem);
        }
        ); 
        tabPanel.add(content);
        }

    menuStore.load(onStoreLoad);
    this.callParent(arguments);
}

});
```

MenuController.js:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MenuController', {

extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

requires: [
    'Ext.dataview.List'
],

config: {
    control: {
        "menutb": {
            activeitemchange: 'onTabPanelActiveItemChange'
        }
    }
},


onTabPanelActiveItemChange: function(othis, value, oldValue, eOpts) {
    var list = value.child('[xtype=list]');
        var mainStore = Ext.getStore('menuItemsStore');
    var results = mainStore.queryBy(function(rec){
        if(rec.get('Level') == 2 && rec.get('Parent') == list.title)
            return true;
    }); 
    var data1  = Ext.Array.pluck(results.getRange(), 'data');
    list.setStore({
        model: 'Mobile.model.MenuItem',
        data: data1 
    });
    var navBar = othis.getParent().getNavigationBar();
    navBar.setTitle(list.title);
}   

});
```

MenuView.js:

```
Ext.define('App.view.MenuView', {
extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
xtype: 'menu',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'App.view.MenuTabPanel'
],
config: {
    id: 'navMenu',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'menutb'
    }
    ]

}
});
```

My app starts from MenuView.js.
What I am doing wrong or what I miss? Or maybe it is problem in android with Lists?

**Edited:**

I find out that there is some problem with activeitemchange event, it fires after initialize. When I commented this event list normally is shown on android. Also when I don't load store and write manually data, the event fires normally.

Comment: Do you see any errors in logcat?

Comment: @Anubis: I test it on device, not emulator

Comment: From ADT menu: Window -> Show view -> Other -> LogCat, there you should see the logs (if the device is connected via USB). Filter by error level and choose only errors.

Comment: Anubis, I don't use eclipse, I build my app with sencha cmd line. ADT is eclipse plugin, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. Still I suppose there should be a way to check your logs, even from command line.

Comment: @Anubis: I tried with network log application, but it writes nothing in log

Comment: @Anubis: I look, there is no error in logcat